# Find row number of match VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find, range, match

In a sheet I have a list of names and in another column an amount associated with it. I need to write these names without repetitions in a column in another sheet. I also need to sum the amounts when the name is repeating.
For example:

```
XXXX 20
YYYY 30
XXXX 10
```

My result should be

```
XXXX 30
YYYY 30
```

I am doing a for loop to go through the names and if I haven't written that name in the result column, I will write it. If I already written it, I will have to stay in the same row and do the sum of the amounts.
The problem is that I tried to use Range.Find, but it always returns Nothing even if the name has been written already.

Here is the code:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rif_reg As Integer
Dim rif_col As Integer
Dim riga_vuota As Integer
Dim rif_foglio As Integer
Dim rowNum As Range

For Each area In Worksheets("XXX").Range("C15:C26,C30:C41,C44:C55,C58:C69").Areas 'more than 1 selected area
    For Each cell In area 'loop through each cell in the selected range
        If IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            If IsNumeric(cell) = False Then
                If Range("A61:A74").Find(What:=cell.Value2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True) is Nothing Then 'search if the name has not being inserted yet
                    Cells(rif_rig + 61, rif_col + 1) = cell 'Nominativo
                    Cells(rif_rig + 61, rif_col + 7) = Worksheets("XXX").Cells(area.Cells(1).Row, rif_col + 1).Value2 'Ruolo
                    Cells(rif_rig + 61, rif_col + 11) = (Worksheets("XXX").Cells(cell.Row, rif_col + 5).Value2 * Worksheets("YYY").Cells(rif_foglio + 32, rif_col + 2)) 'Quota Lordo
                    rif_rig = rif_rig + 1
                Else
                    Set rowNum = Range("A61:A74").Find(What:=cell.Value2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
                    Cells(rowNum.Row, rif_col + 11) = (Cells(rowNum.Row, rif_col + 11) + Worksheets("XXX").Cells(cell.Row, rif_col + 5).Value2 * Worksheets("YYY").Cells(rif_foglio + 32, rif_col + 2)) 'Quota Lordo
                    If Cells(rowNum.Row, rif_col + 7) <> Worksheets("XXX").Cells(area.Cells(1).Row, rif_col + 1).Value2 Then
                        Cells(rowNum.Row, rif_col + 7) = Cells(rowNum.Row, rif_col + 8) & "," & Worksheets("XXX").Cells(area.Cells(1).Row, rif_col + 1).Value2 'Ruolo
                    Else
                        Cells(rowNum.Row, rif_col + 7) = Worksheets("XXX").Cells(area.Cells(1).Row, rif_col + 1).Value2 'Ruolo
                    End If
                End If
            Else
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next
areaCount = areaCount + 1
Next
```

Since this hasn't worked I tried using Application.Match but this does not give me the correct row number

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rif_reg As Integer
Dim rif_col As Integer
Dim riga_vuota As Integer
Dim rif_foglio As Integer
Dim rowNum As Long

For Each area In Worksheets("XXX").Range("C15:C26,C30:C41,C44:C55,C58:C69").Areas 'more than 1 selected area
    For Each cell In area 'loop through each cell in the selected range
        If IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
            If IsNumeric(cell) = False Then
                If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value2, Range("A61:A74"), 0)) Then 'search if the name has not being inserted yet
                    Cells(rif_rig + 61, rif_col + 1) = cell 'Nominativo
                    Cells(rif_rig + 61, rif_col + 7) = Worksheets("XXX").Cells(area.Cells(1).Row, rif_col + 1).Value2 'Ruolo
                    Cells(rif_rig + 61, rif_col + 11) = (Worksheets("XXX").Cells(cell.Row, rif_col + 5).Value2 * Worksheets("YYY").Cells(rif_foglio + 32, rif_col + 2)) 'Quota Lordo
                    rif_rig = rif_rig + 1
                Else
                    rowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cell.Value2, Range("A61:A74"), 0)
                    Cells(rowNum, rif_col + 11) = (Cells(rowNum, rif_col + 11) + Worksheets("XXX").Cells(cell.Row, rif_col + 5).Value2 * Worksheets("YYY").Cells(rif_foglio + 32, rif_col + 2)) 'Quota Lordo
                    If Cells(rowNum, rif_col + 7) <> Worksheets("XXX").Cells(area.Cells(1).Row, rif_col + 1).Value2 Then
                        Cells(rowNum, rif_col + 7) = Cells(rowNum, rif_col + 8) & "," & Worksheets("XXX").Cells(area.Cells(1).Row, rif_col + 1).Value2 'Ruolo
                    Else
                        Cells(rowNum, rif_col + 7) = Worksheets("XXX").Cells(area.Cells(1).Row, rif_col + 1).Value2 'Ruolo
                    End If
                End If
            Else
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next
areaCount = areaCount + 1
Next
```

Thanks,
Carlotta.

P.S. I am new to VBA so my code could be very messy

Comment: Why not just use a pivot table?

Comment: Whenever you use `Range()` or `Cells()` you need to qualify that with a specific worksheet object, otherwise your code *might* work or not, depending on which sheet happens to be active.

Comment: ...also there seems to be a bunch of missing code, and some of the variables you use are not the ones you declared - eg `rif_reg` vs `rif_rig`

Comment: @BigBen - you are right because I selected the wrong line of code. I ment to select the Find code in the first macro. `rowNum = Range("A61:A74").Find(What:=cell.Value2, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Row`

Comment: @GMalc - except it's better to test if the find succeeded first, instead of chaining the `.Row` on the end.

Comment: @BigBen - I agree, but in the first macro that's what the OPs first range find is doing.

Comment: Than you all for yor comments! I will review them and modify my code accordingly!

Comment: i never get tired showing the benefits of [SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee692882(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) when computing data, even in Excel (as that should have been done i a database, before the data moves to Excel).Query looks like `Select nameOf, Sum(Amount) FROM Sheet1$ GROUP BY nameOf;` simple (once you get the point on it) and fast ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to iterate over all areas in the range (it's about `For Each area In Worksheets("XXX")...`). Just loop over the cells in the range, the range object will take care of showing them all to you.

Also, don't write all ranges into a macro. You will have to change the code each time to select other cells. It's easier to select the desired cells before running the macro and use the Selection object (please do not worry that there is so much text here - in fact, there are less than 30 lines of code, all the rest are comments for you):

```
Sub SumsByNames()
Dim rSource As Range
Dim aCell As Range  ' Iterate by each cells in current Selection
Dim aData As Variant    ' Array for Names and ranges with this Name
Dim i As Long
    aData = Array() ' Empty array
    Set rSource = Application.Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    For Each aCell In rSource ' If cell is not empty then .text also not empty string
        If aCell.Text <> vbNullString Then
            If Not IsNumeric(aCell) Then
                Call addToData(aData, aCell.Text, aCell.Offset(0, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next aCell
    Set aCell = Worksheets("Result").Range("A61")
    aCell.CurrentRegion.ClearContents
    For i = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
        aCell.Value = aData(i)(0)   ' Paste Name
        aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(aData(i)(1))
        Set aCell = aCell.Offset(1, 0)
    Next i
End Sub

Sub addToData(ByRef aData As Variant, sName As String, rCell As Range)
Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(aData) To UBound(aData)
        If aData(i)(0) = sName Then
            Set aData(i)(1) = Application.Union(aData(i)(1), rCell)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
    i = UBound(aData) + 1
    ReDim Preserve aData(i)
    aData(i) = Array(sName, rCell)
End Sub
```

Example file [mySumIf_TestDemo.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/txufau8l1g9a81f/mySumIf_TestDemo.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: Please try to select cells with NAME X ... NAME Z and only those cells (without data to be summarized) before running the macro.

Comment: Do this on your raw data sheet. The macro will collect all the names that you have selected, take care of their uniqueness (skip duplicates) and sum the values ​​in the next cell to the right of the cell with the name. The results will be written to another sheet (I have it called "Result", you may have a different sheet name) starting from cell A61

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried your code, but this is what I obtained: 
'1  NAME X    3   NAME Y  2   NAME W  NAME Z '
However what I wanted was this: ` NAME X NAME Y NAME W NAME Z ` Also the sum I have to make is coming from another worksheet

Comment: Thanks! I understand where the problem is now!

Comment: @CarlottaFabris I changed the code a little to avoid errors and speed up the macro a little, and added a demo file

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adapt this code

```
Sub test()
    
    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim CollNames As Collection
    Dim Cella As Range
    Dim R As Long
    
    Set Sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foglio1") 'origine
    Set Sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foglio2") 'destinazione
    Set CollNames = New Collection
    With Sh1
        R = 1
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each Cella In .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) 
            CollNames.Add Sh2.Cells(R, 1), CStr(Cella)
            If Err.Number = 0 Then
                CollNames(Cella) = Cella
                R = R + 1
            Else
                Err.Clear
            End If
            CollNames(Cella).Offset(0, 1) = CollNames(Cella).Offset(0, 1) + Cella.Offset(0, 1)
        Next Cella
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    Set Sh1 = Nothing
    Set Sh2 = Nothing
    Set CollNames = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

The code reads data in columns A and B of Sh1 and reports the result in the same columns of Sh2.

You need to modify the range in the For Each statement and the offset.